# How to change tab from parent in react material Tabs

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

I've got a component like FeedSwitcher with two tabs inside

one for the general feed the other one only for the posts of the current user

in FeedSwitcher component at the start the value is 0 therefore
the current user can view all the feed.

```
const FeedSwitcher = ({feed, posts, user }: FeedSwitcherProps) => {
  const classes = useStyles();
  const [value, setValue] = useState(0);

  const handleChange = (event: React.ChangeEvent<{}>, newValue: number) => {
    setValue(newValue);
  };
  return (
    <div className={classes.root}>
      <Tabs
        value={value}
        onChange={handleChange}
        variant="fullWidth"
        indicatorColor="primary"
        textColor="primary"
        aria-label="switcher tabs"
      >
        <Tab icon={<PeopleIcon />} aria-label="phone" />
        <Tab icon={<PersonIcon />} aria-label="favorite" />
      </Tabs>
      <TabPanel value={value} index={0}>
        <Feed feed={feed} />
      </TabPanel>
      <TabPanel value={value} index={1}>
        <Posts posts={posts} user={user} />
      </TabPanel>
    </div>
  );
};
```

After the current user post a new thread

(the form is in the parent component)

I want to show the tab with  index 1

How can set the value from the parent?

Should I use a redux state or is there
an other direct and simpler way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The state needs to be in the parent component.

You can feed the child component with the value, and pass it a function argument like `onValueChange` that it can use to trigger an update on the parent's state.

```js
// in parent
const [feedSwitcherValue, setFeedSwitcherValue] = useState(0);
return (
  <FeedSwitcher
    feed={feed}
    posts={posts}
    user={user}
    value={feedSwitcherValue}
    onValueChange={value => setFeedSwitcherValue(value)}
  />
);
```

```js
// child
const FeedSwitcher = ({feed, posts, user, value, onValueChange }: FeedSwitcherProps) => {
  const classes = useStyles();

  const handleChange = (event: React.ChangeEvent<{}>, newValue: number) => {
    onValueChange(newValue);
  };
  return (
    <div className={classes.root}>
      <Tabs
        value={value}
        onChange={handleChange}
        variant="fullWidth"
        indicatorColor="primary"
        textColor="primary"
        aria-label="switcher tabs"
      >
        <Tab icon={<PeopleIcon />} aria-label="phone" />
        <Tab icon={<PersonIcon />} aria-label="favorite" />
      </Tabs>
      <TabPanel value={value} index={0}>
        <Feed feed={feed} />
      </TabPanel>
      <TabPanel value={value} index={1}>
        <Posts posts={posts} user={user} />
      </TabPanel>
    </div>
  );
};
```

Comment: My first attempt :) but it doesn't work thanks for the reply

Comment: Start from there and update us on what's not working :)